# php 5.3 page not compatible/working on BlueHost servers which have php 4.3?

Tags: php, mysql, version

I have the following teachers.php page, developed by a freelancer. He says it works on his localhost and he is using php 5.3, but the only reason it doesn't work when we upload it to our servers, and BlueHost has v.4.3 is because of the older version.

I am awaiting a response on how he can resolve this, assuming he will say he can, but would be interested in any responses/suggestions/solutions.

What is causing the error (what lines of code) and what are the best solutions to get around this?

the page in question does some teacher tracking:

The start of the code in the page is as follows:

```
<?php
require_once("scripts/connect_db.php");

session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['teacher'])) header('Location: teacher_login.php');;
$result="";
if (isset($_POST["logout"])) {


    session_destroy();

   header('Location:index.php');

}
$err = "";
if (isset($_POST["add_class"]) && !empty($_POST['class_names']) && $_SESSION['teacher']) {
    $class_name         = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['class_names']);
    $school_pin         = $_SESSION['teacher_school_pin'];
    $teacher_username   = $_SESSION['teacher_username'];
    $teacher_id         = $_SESSION['teacher_id'];

    $query = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO classes (teacher_username, teacher_id,school_pin, class_name) 
    VALUES('$teacher_username','$teacher_id', '$school_pin', '$class_name')");
}
if (isset($_POST["track_button"])) {
  $var          = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['user_name']); 
  $quiz         = @mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['quiz']);
  $school_pin   = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['school_pin']);
  $class_name   = @mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['class_name']);
  $top   = @mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['top']);

    $array_one = comma_separated_to_array($var);

    $query = array();
    if($quiz != "non"){
        array_push($query," quiz_id=".$quiz." ");
    }
    if(count($array_one) != 0){
        array_push($query," username IN ('".implode("','",$array_one)."') ");
    }
    if(!empty($class_name)){
        if($class_name !== "all"){        
            array_push($query,"  class_name='".$class_name."' ");
        }
    }
    if(!empty($school_pin)){
        array_push($query,"  school_pin='".$school_pin."' ");
    }
    if($quiz == "non"){
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT DISTINCT username FROM quiz_takers WHERE ".implode(" AND ",$query)." ORDER BY percentage DESC LIMIT ".$top);
        if(!$result)$err = "Enter Your student data to Track, Please!";
    }else{
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM quiz_takers WHERE ".implode(" AND ",$query)." ORDER BY percentage DESC LIMIT ".$top);
        if(!$result)$err = "Enter Your student data to Track, Please!";
    }
    if(@mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0){
        $err = "No Result Found!";
    }
}
$all_classes     = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT class_name FROM classes WHERE teacher_username='".$_SESSION['teacher_username']."'");
```

Comment: For one thing. the *mysqli* extension didn't exist until PHP 5. I'm honestly really shocked there are still PHP 4.3 servers running - it hasn't been supported for **13 years**. If upgrading even to V5 is out of the question, then you'd need to convert this to use the older *mysql* extension, although be aware that there are many known security issues with it (as there are with any unsupported PHP version, especially one this old)

Comment: @iainn - that's helpful, thank you

Comment: I just checked and what would also be helpful is clarifying the difference between what it says on the cpanel: PHP 5.6.32   and in myphpadmin: phpMyAdmin Version information: 4.3.8, latest stable version: 4.7.7. What is what? Does the phpMyAdmin version affect code written in 5.6?

Comment: PHP 4 already had a legacy status a decade ago, and today that's what's happening to PHP 5. Fix your dependenices, find a way to upgrade. Not only is upgrading an option, it's probably an easier option than maintaining this ancient code. You probably wouldn't be able to compile PHP 4 if you tried today.

Comment: Thanks Narf - could you read the latest comment. I appear to have gotten confused between phpMyAdmin version and php and need clarification on the difference and why certain mysqli functions are not working on our server